# Pnotify Post message via webservice

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, pnotify

I'm fairly new to the programming world of Jquery. 
I am trying to get data from a web service to be viewed on a notification via Pnotify. 
However, on each page load the script does not view the notification bar. I really don't understand what I'm doing wrong. Hope you can help.

NOTE: the web service does retrieve the data correctly in JSON format.

UPDATED: I am able to do a msg.d but it retrieves the JSON but does not parse the information how I would like it to.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $.ajax({ //DATA REQUEST
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'WebServices.asmx/getNote',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (msg) {
        $.pnotify({ //CALL PNotify 
        title: msg.NoteTitle,                               
        text: msg.NoteText
        });
       }                
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: What is pnotify? The first step in debugging this should be to use your browser's developer console (or equivalent) to make sure the request actually completes, and/or replace the `$.pnotify` call with a call to `alert` to verify you receive a response.

Comment: Pnotify is a JavaScript notification plugin. I'm going to go ahead and try what you said and see what comes of it.

Comment: Chris Laplante - I've been debugging and so far I can get the JSON in the notification but I am unable to get the specific data I need to display.

Comment: Does `alert(msg.NoteTitle) ` give anything meaningful?

Comment: alert(msg.NoteTitle) didn't do anything for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reviewed your code and if you do the following you should be able to get the data you need. 
You need to be aware that object that always need to be parsed before passing the array to a view.
In your case you didn't do that.

```
 success: function (msg) {
               var Obj= eval(msg["d"]); or // $.parseJSON(msg["d"]) Method to evaluate Json

$.pnotify({ //CALL PNotify 
title: Obj["0"].NotificationText, // The pared arrays
text: Obj["0"].NotificationDescription
```

Comment: This is both incorrect and dangerous advice. When dataType is specified as "json", jQuery automatically parses the JSON response and returns a Javascript object. Even if that weren't the case, calling eval on the response is a bad idea, and you should instead use a JSON parsing library.

Comment: User.... : I was able to do as you said and got the data out. I am aware that that is the quick and dirty way as Chris L explained. However, I just wanted to get the data out.

Comment: J. Ballard: Although Chris is right about the eval you can also use $.parseJSON(msg["d"]) instead of eval. I don't know what kind of system your adding this too but it is a closed system and not open to the public you should be fine. I have done this will Pnotify a couple times on my intranet system with no issues so far. Best of luck with arrays if you choose to take my advice.

Comment: Thanks for the help user1880670 you've been a great deal of help to me. It is a closed system I'm working wit by the way.